# multiple layout through block coding in magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I'm new to magento. I don`t have permission to modify the controller file. So I'm creating new module with block to make my requirement works. Now everything works fine.

But, now based on the condition, i need to load the different layout. (one with left sidebar and another without left sidebar). I have to load the layout xml file through block code.

I don't know how to do with block. Can anyone help me?

Comment: have you tried this solution ???

Comment: @Asifhhh I have tried but no solution yet. I think your solution will help me to acheive my target. I'll try and let you know. thanks for answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed myself.

In block, changed layout instead of removing `left` sidebar.

```
protected function _prepareLayout() {


        if($my_condition)
        {        

            $this->getLayout()->getBlock('root')->setTemplate("page/1column.phtml");

        }

        parent::_prepareLayout();        
        return $this;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello you set your template into your layout xml like below

```
<reference name="root">   
      <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>   
    </reference>
<reference name="root">   
      <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columnleft.phtml</template></action>   
    </reference>
```

Comment: I need to load the template / layout based on the condition.

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571169/magento-conditional-block-in-layout-xml

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below solution.
First of all you cannot easly add two different layout for a specific page

```
<checkout_index_cart>
<reference name="root">
 <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
...
<checkout_index_cart>

<checkout_onepage_index>

<reference name="root">
 <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
...
<checkout_onepage_index>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the page layout on the bases of condition, defined in helper function

```
<reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template helper="modulename/getNewLayoutupdate"/></action>
</reference>
```

Here is the helper function, make there conditions accordingly

```
  public function getNewLayoutupdate(){

    $page_layout = Mage::getStoreConfig('customize_your_own');

    switch($page_layout)
    {
        case 'empty':
            $page_layout = 'page/empty.phtml';
            break;
        case 'one_column':
            $page_layout = "page/1column.phtml";
            break;
        case 'two_columns_left':
            $page_layout = 'page/2columns-left.phtml';
            break;
        case 'two_columns_right':
            $page_layout = 'page/2columns-right.phtml';
            break;
        case 'three_columns':
            $page_layout = 'page/3columns.phtml';
            break;
        default:
            $page_layout = 'page/2columns-right.phtml';
    }

    return $page_layout;

}
```

Comment: I have done as you said. but my module helper overrides the existing catalog module helper. so i'm getting error like `Namespace_Catalog_Helper_Category_Flat  not found`

Comment: well you do not have your own module's helper ? Data.php ?

Comment: how did you set this code ? <template helper="modulename/getNewLayoutupdate"/> and where "getNewLayoutupdate" function is defined ?

Comment: Thanks i have fixed. It's simple. Let me answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to update the layout xml.

Check this tutorial: http://magento-quickies.tumblr.com/post/16336482158/adding-additional-layout-xml-updates-via-modules